# Is there any historical database on witches?

Tags: historical

Is there any historical database, in any form, relating to witches? It can be text-based, a spreadsheet, or just a list of numbers, or anything.

For example: a list of witches executed per year and various characteristics about them.

Comment: +1 I just checked Wikidata and am surprised that it contains zero instance of witch.